# Merge sort not working completely

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, mergesort

The code that I have made for merge sort is given below. The thing is that on giving the input the output is **3 2 1 5 0**. What is going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int d[100];

void merge(int a[], int b[], int c[], int n)
{
int n2=floor(n/2);
int i=0, j=0, k=0;
while(i<n2 && j<(n-n2))
{
    if(b[i]<c[j])
    {
        d[k++]=b[i++];
    }
    else if(b[i]>c[j])
    {
        d[k++]=c[j++];
    }
}
    if(i==n2)
    {
        if(j<(n-n2))
        {
            d[k++]=c[j++];
        }
    }
    if(i<n2)
    {
        d[k++]=b[i++];
    }
}


void mergesort(int a[], int n)
{
int n2=floor(n/2);
int b[50],c[50];
int i,j=0,k=0;
for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
{
    b[i]=a[k++];
}
while(k<n)
{
    c[j++]=a[k++];
}
merge(a,b,c,n);
}

int main()
{
int a[]={5,4,3,2,1};
int n=5;
mergesort(a,n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cout<<d[i]<<endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried going step by step using paper or a debugger to inspect values?

Comment: Yes:  What have you tried to find the problem?

Comment: Try this instead http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/mergeSort.htm

Comment: I did it on paper and called the mergesort function again. But after that too it was not working. Thus I asked but forgot to include the call. I had saved it in a different folder. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that the arrays (b and c) passed to merge are not sorted.
Other problems are that the algorithm is not recursive and that merge
does not always put all numbers from b and c into a.

A version that seems to work with minimal changes to your code would be

```
void merge(int a[], int b[], int c[], int n)
{
  int n2=floor(n/2);
  int i=0, j=0, k=0;
  while(k<n)
  {
    if((j == (n-n2) || b[i]<c[j]) && i < n2)
    {
      a[k++]=b[i++];
    }
    else
    {
      a[k++]=c[j++];
    }
  }
}


void mergesort(int a[], int n)
{
  int n2=floor(n/2);
  int b[50],c[50];
  int i,j=0,k=0;
  for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
  {
    b[i]=a[k++];
  }
  while(k<n)
  {
    c[j++]=a[k++];
  }
  if(n2 > 1) {
    mergesort(b, n2);
  }
  if(n - n2 > 1) {
    mergesort(c, n - n2);
  }
  merge(a,b,c,n);
}

int main()
{
  int a[]={5,4,3,2,1};
  int n=5;
  mergesort(a,n);
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cout<<a[i]<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well done for getting rid of the global d :-) BTW What does a = {1,5,4,3,2,1} do?

Comment: In the merge function in the if condition shouldn't it be (j<=n-n2)

Comment: @doctorlove : If you pass inn {1,5,4,3,2,1} it will result in {1,1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: @doctorlove : Did you remember to increase n from 5 to 6?

Comment: @PrakharMohan : Yeah, it just makes sure you don't copy elements from c into a if all elements from c has already been copied. In that case elements should be taken from b.

Answer (score 2):

It is conventional to call merge_sort recursively in order to sort each subrange until the subrange is just one long then merge these together.

In your `mergesort`, `b` takes the first n/2 values of `a`, that is 5 and 4.
`c` takes the remaining values 3,2,1.

You then call `merge` (BTW Why do you pass `a[]` to this? It isn't used)
The first loop

```
while(i<n2 && j<(n-n2))
```

will have `n2 = 2` and `n-n2 = 5-2 = 3`
This puts 3 at the start since `b[0]>c[0]=3` and 2 next since `b[1]>c[1]=2` and 1 at `d[2]` for similar reasons.
Since you don't recurse you won't sort these.
You then finish the while loop with i = 0 which is less than n2.
You just say

```
if(i<n2)
```

so you just copy the first thing from b which is 5.

All this gives 3, 2, 1, 5, and 0 because you made `d` global.

Answer (score 1):

The input for merge need to be sorted arrays, as Philip mentioned before. Mergesort is recursive. For this you need to divide them till you reach a point where you only have one element in the array (so it is sorted) and merge all arrays to become the sorted result for the input. Wikipedia is your friend to understand the algorithm: [Mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Btw: You need to ensure that one of both cases in the comparison in the merge checks also on equality of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Philip is right, there's no **recursive** in your code at all.

However, there are some more errors. I've marked it with annotations, just as a postscript of Philip's.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int d[100];

void merge(int a[], int b[], int c[], int n)
{
    int n2=floor(n/2);
    int i=0, j=0, k=0;
    while(i<n2 && j<(n-n2))
    {
        if(b[i]<c[j])
        {
            d[k++]=b[i++];
        }
        else if(b[i]>c[j])
        {
            d[k++]=c[j++];
        }
        /***************************************************/
        /* What if b[i] == c[j] here?                      */
        /* Your code will drop into an infinity loop.      */
        /***************************************************/
    }
    if(i==n2)
    {
        if(j<(n-n2))
        /****************************************************/
        /* Use **while** here?                              */
        /* Because there may be more than one elements left */
        /* in c[].                                          */
        /****************************************************/
        {
            d[k++]=c[j++];
        }
    }
    if(i<n2)
    /***************************************************/
    /* Use **while** here? - With the same reason      */
    /***************************************************/
    {
        d[k++]=b[i++];
    }
}


void mergesort(int a[], int n)
{
    int n2=floor(n/2);
    int b[50],c[50];
    int i,j=0,k=0;
    for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
    {
        b[i]=a[k++];
    }
    while(k<n)
    {
        c[j++]=a[k++];
    }
    merge(a,b,c,n);
}

int main()
{
    int a[]={5,4,3,2,1};
    int n=5;
    mergesort(a,n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<d[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
void merge(T arr[], int begin, int mid, int end)
{
    int len = end - begin;
    T *temp = new T[len];
    int i = begin;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k = 0;
    while (i <= mid && j <= end)
    {
        if(arr[i] <= arr[j])
            temp[k++] = arr[i++];
        else
            temp[k++] = arr[j++];
    }
    while (i <= mid)
        temp[k++] = arr[i++];
    while(j <= end)
        temp[k++] = arr[j++];

    memcpy(arr + begin, temp, len*sizeof(T));
    delete []temp;
}
template <typename T>
void mergeSort(T arr[], int begin, int end)
{
    if (begin >= end)
        return;

    int mid = (end + begin) / 2;
    mergeSort(arr, begin, mid);
    mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, end);
    merge(arr, begin, mid, end);
}
```